# Using $(this).find('class') inside insertAfter()

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I have the following code to view the images uploaded under `<input type="file"`

```
$(document).on("change", ".files", function(e) {
        var files = e.target.files,
            filesLength = files.length;
            $(this).find('.pip').remove();
        for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
            var f = files[i]
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
            var file = e.target;           
            $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
                "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\">" +
                "<br/><span class=\"remove\"><i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i></span>" +
                "</span>").insertAfter(".file-upload");
            $(".remove").click(function(){
                $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
            });            
            });
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
        });
```

The class `file-upload` get duplicated on a click of a button. So i want to target the current div like this `insertAfter($(this).find(".file-upload"))`? Does that even work? I tried to do but it didn't work. How can I achieve that?

I tried to use `append` but that did not help either.

**Edit**
My HTML

```
<div class="medi">
   <div class="file-upload">
      <input type="file" class="files" name="images[]" multiple="">
      <img src="/upload.png" style="position: relative;top: 11px;height: 16px;width: 16px;margin-left: 8px;">
      <span class="upload-text">Upload</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

This section gets duplicated.

Comment: Can you give us your html?

Comment: @angel.bonev I have added my HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you code `this` refers to input, so you need to find [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) `.file-upload` parent, you can use [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) but you need to keep that structure (I prefer closest)

Don't add events in for-loop becouse if you select 3 files your first `remove element` will have 3 [click events](https://api.jquery.com/click/), 2 on the second and one on the last one

```js
$(document).on("change", ".files", function (e) {
    var files = e.target.files,
            filesLength = files.length;
    //this reffer's to <input type="file" class="files" .. so you need to get closest parent .file-upload
    let div = $(this).closest(".file-upload");
    $(div).find('.pip').remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        var f = files[i]
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (function (e) {
            var file = e.target;
            $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
                    "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\">" +
                    "<br/><span class=\"remove\"><i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i></span>" +
                    "</span>").insertAfter($(div));
        });
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
    $(div).find(".remove").click(function () {
        $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
    });
});
```

```css
img {
    max-width: 80px;
    max-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="medi">
    <div class="file-upload">
        <input type="file" class="files" name="images[]" multiple="">
        <img src="/upload.png" style="position: relative;top: 11px;height: 16px;width: 16px;margin-left: 8px;">
        <span class="upload-text">Upload</span>
    </div>
</div>
```